# How to upgrade Grails 2.4 to 2.5

Tags: grails

How to upgrade `Grails 2.4.4` to `2.5.0` ?

I am using STS

```
Version: 3.6.4.RELEASE
Build Id: 201503100339
Platform: Eclipse Luna SR1 (4.4.2)

Grails 2.4.4.
Mac 10.10
Java jdk1.8.0_45.jdk
```

Comment: https://github.com/grails/grails-core/releases/tag/v2.5.0

Comment: http://totalprogus.blogspot.in/2015/03/upgrade-grails-244-to-250.html

Comment: I just want to know the basic command i need to type in order to upgrade grails from 2.4.4 to s.5.0. I am a newbie.

Comment: Then set `grails` `v2.5.0` and  run `grails upgrade` commands from the console.

Comment: where should i set `grails v2.5.0` ?

Comment: In your classpath or if you are using gvm then user grails version 2.5.0. and run the command

Comment: Can you give me the exact command. I am a bit new to this.

Comment: run `grails -version` in the console and see what is your current grails version. Is it 2.5.0?

Comment: Install gvm http://gvmtool.net/ and then install grails 2.5.0
`gvm i grails 2.5.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The grails upgrade command is gone from 2.4. You have to run set-grails-version

```
grails set-grails-version 2.5.6
```

Then go into BuildConfig.groovy and manually upgrade your dependencies/plugins:
https://github.com/grails/grails-core/releases/tag/v2.5.0